# Where is Visual studio 2012 Setup project template?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to make the set up file but I unable to find any template to develop setup file.its seems like MS dump the set up wizard template.

I've tried with publish project and I got set up file. but not sure its good approach.

Comment: You mean [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).ASPX)?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Visual studio 2012` the `MS Deployment projects` are deprecated. You can use [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) instead.

Comment: If I publish the project then I got set up file. Is it good approach
?

Comment: What you mean by `publish the project`?

Comment: if you right click on the Project and you can get publish option and there you can publish the project and able to make the setup file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Install Shield template. It's coming up with Visual Studio 2012 and 2013